# Counting unique repetitions in a string with Python

Tags: python

Recently I have been trying to make a list of the unique repetitions in a string but have failed in all my attempts. For example the program needs to find the duplicate of a letter or number then move on tho the next part of the string.

For example the program could output the finished result as a string:

```
Input = "aaabbaabbbba"
Output = "3/2/2/4/1"
```

or a list:

```
Input = "001000011111001"
Output = [2,1,4,5,2,1]
```

I would prefer if anybody trying to come up with a solutuion did not use any external packages of libraries as this code is going onto a microcontroller that does not support packages

Comment: if you want to turn your list of integers into the string with the slashes, you can you this:
`'/'.join(map(str,runs))` where `runs` is your output list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your dscription as I understand it will work for you :

```py
def find_unique_repetitions(string):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return []

    repetitions = []
    count = 1
    for i in range(len(string)-1):
        if string[i] == string[i+1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            repetitions.append(count)
            count = 1
    repetitions.append(count)
    return repetitions

# Test the function
input_string = "aaabbaabbbba"
output_list = find_unique_repetitions(input_string)
print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 2, 4, 1]
```

Comment: What is `find_unique_repetitions('')`?

Comment: It was not the case but now it supports @Manfred

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need:

```
def ur(s: str) -> list[int]:
    p = None
    r = []
    for c in s:
        if c == p:
            r[-1] += 1
        else:
            p = c
            r.append(1)
    return r


for arg in 'aaabbaabbbba', '001000011111001', '':
    print(ur(arg))
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 2, 2, 4, 1]
[2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1]
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `solution` function passes your input, so here you go

```py
from itertools import groupby

def solution(text):
    return [len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(text)]
```

Comment: this one is more pythonic than the other solutions. `itertools` is a powerful built-in library but it's not well known :)

Comment: You can even avoid materialising a list with the items in each group, and just count what the iterator yields: `return [sum(1 for _ in g) for _, g in groupby(text)]`